# Rollover button that causes an image to appear

Tags: flash, rollover, fla

I am trying to create an interactive office seating chart where when you hover over an employees cubicle an employee description appears.

I have created the employee descriptions in Photoshop and I was able to turn them into rollover buttons in flash, the only problem is that the whole description when rolled over even if it is invisible appears.I want to be able to just rollover the employees cubicle and have the description appear.

Attached is what I have so far:

SWF File:
https://www.mediafire.com/?w1aa26qp1rwi13p

Flash Fla file:
https://www.mediafire.com/?w1aa26qp1rwi13p

Please help me resolve this issue. I know it is simple but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks,

Comment: I want it to function like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEyJuT8SSME

Answer (score 0):

This website has the solution

http://convergence.journalism.missouri.edu/?p=536